# Swift Execute command line command in Sandbox mode

Tags: swift, cocoa, command-line, appstore-sandbox

Currently I am trying to get my hands on Swift programming. I try to execute a command line command from within my **macOS Swift application**. Without setting my application being sandboxed everything is working fine. But since I activate the Sandbox the command will no longer work but does not throw any errors and terminates with status code `0`.

So the simplest use case is to start `VSCode` from my application.

The method which is responsible for executing the shell commands is the following:

```
 func executeUserCommand(command: String, args: [String]?) -> Int32{
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/" + command
        task.arguments = args
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        return task.terminationStatus
    }
}
```

So if I want to start `VSCode` I call `executeUserCommand("code", ["."])` for opening `VSCode` in the current directory.

This works fine until I enable the `App Sandbox` in Xcode. I clean and rebuild the application, but now `VSCode` does not start at all, but the terminationStatus is `0`. I am pretty sure that the sandbox restricts the access to the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Is there any way of giving my application access to only this specific folder ? So that the user can grant my application access to the folder once, and then the application can access the folder, even after a restart of the application ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is exactly what app sandboxing is inteded to prevent.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought so, but I was thinking about if it is possible to explicitly ask the user to give the application the permission for this specific folder

Comment: Don't you think you should find out why you need to sandbox your application?

Comment: I want to make it available via the App Store and  if I am not mistaken a restriction is that the app then needs to be sandboxed.

Comment: read the manual https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH1-SW1

Comment: In my testing, `/usr/local/bin` is restricted as you say, but `/usr/bin` is not. I assume `code` is a VSCode command? Can it be installed into `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`? Or perhaps use `open` from there like so: `/usr/bin/open /Applications/Notes.app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yeah, I already thought so, but I was thinking about if it is possible to explicitly ask the user to give the application the permission for this specific folder

You are thinking in the right direction. Clearly sandboxes apps would be pretty useless if they couldn't access files and folders, and the key to them doing so is the user granting them permission. This permission is granted using the standard open and save dialogs, when the user selects a file/folder the app is granted permission to read/write/create it.

Need access to a specific file/folder? Customise the open dialog to guide the user to select that particular file/folder, and check the result to make sure they have - handling the situation when they choose not to.

Wish your app to retain across launches the access right granted by the user to to a file/folder? Then you need to create and store a *security scoped bookmark*.

Time to do some reading, if you get stuck ask a new question and someone will undoubtedly help you. Remember to show what you've found out, code you've written, etc.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions and workflows on how to accomplish such a task. I already tried the security scoped boookmark approach but it didn’t work so I guess I messed something up. I will definitely try it again

Comment: I found these classes very useful in understanding how to implement sandboxing in a macOS app: [AppSandboxFileAccess](https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess). I ended up incorporating them into my app.