# Calling git commands from within a Swift macOS application

Tags: swift, git, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to call terminal commands from within my application, specifically git commands. 
In the simplest case, let's just say that I want to call `git status` for a given directory.

The purpose of my application is a wrapper around git to provide the use of git tools, without any direct user interaction with the command line (think Sourcetree).

When attempting to call `git status` using the normal method for running commands in Swift

```
func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [String]) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    task.arguments = arguments

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    return output
}

print(shell(launchPath: "/usr/bin/git", arguments: ["status"]))
```

I (understandably) receive the error `xcrun: error: cannot be used within an App Sandbox.`

I can get around this by disabling security settings, and App Sandbox in the `.entitlements` file, however this is obviously not a preferable thing to do.

Is there a way I can allow my application to be granted to use `/usr/bin/git` within certain directories?

Many thanks.

Comment: "Is there a way I can allow my application to be granted to use /usr/bin/git within certain directories?" I don't know much how apple's sandbox works but I doubt it. If you run an arbitrary comand in some directory it is possible to break out of it. Git is not an exclusion, it has a lot of options to work outside of current directory and not designed to restrict anything itself

Comment: however check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48242009/2303202

Comment: You could use an NSOpenPanel to make the user point at the directory you want to work in, then save persistently the security scoped bookmark associated with the URL and use it everytime you need to access this location.

Comment: Take a look at http://gitup.co, which has an open source framework to interact with git repos.

Comment: It seems that because it's git uses xcrun, which people have had issues with when trying GCC and CLang within a sandbox in the past. I'm not sure where to head from here.

@max630 Thanks a lot, but I think the permissions within the folder is not actually the issue here (though I did frame it more that way so thanks for the response).

Comment: @Avi thanks a lot, I'll take a look at that!

Comment: @EricAya: Any news regarding this issue?

Comment: Why is settings the App Sandbox option in .entitlements file to false bad? Is it only bad if you want to distribute it via the App Store? Asking because I'm trying to create an internal tool.

Comment: Shame there's no "git for macOS" equivalent of the "git for Windows" SDK. Have been searching but no results thus far.

Comment: Spoke too soon! Found a promising link https://bdewey.com/til/2022/07/23/using-git-from-swift/